# How can I cache a rest Request using java?

Tags: java, rest, caching

I'm working on a Java project using Spring Integration for consuming a REST webservice just for retrieving information. The web service responses change once a month. The amount of requests is huge, so I want to decrease the network traffic. Is it possible to do this using a cache proxy or is there any better tool for this task?

Comment: any framework that you are using?

Comment: I'm actually using Spring Integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring you can use [Spring Cache](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html). That and a CacheManager that expires after 30 days. If you have Java 8 you can use Caffeine:

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {

   final CaffeineCacheManager manager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
   final Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeineBuilder = Caffeine.newBuilder()
                         .expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.DAYS);
   manager.setCaffeine(caffeineBuilder);
   return manager;

}
```